# Bar Chart Part 1 D3 why does it skip data that is the same value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Not sure why but my code...which is also very closely following the D3 Bar graph .js tutorial found here: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html

Does not draw rectangles for data with the same values from the variable "dataset".  Can anyone explain why? or how to fix it?

```
var dataset = [5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 50] ;

var w = setWidthToWindow();  //setWidthToWindow
var h = setHeightToWindow();  //setHeightToWindow
var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
      .range([0, w/2]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(dataset)
      .rangeBands([0, 120]);



var chart = d3.select("#over_rating")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("class", "chart")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", 20 * dataset.length);


chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("y", y)
     .attr("width", x )
     .attr("height", y.rangeBand());




chart.selectAll("text")
     .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("text")
     .attr("x", w/2 + 15)
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d) + y.rangeBand() / 2; })
     .attr("dx", 3) // padding-right
     .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
     .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
     .text(String);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an ordinal scale and positioning your bars based on the data *value*, not the index, so all the data with the value '1' scales to exactly the same position. If you look at your svg, you'll see there are three bars drawn in exactly the same place.

I guess you could set up the scale with index values:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
      .rangeBands([0, 120]);
```

and then scale by the index:

```
 .attr("y", function(d,i) { return y(i); })
```

which would allow you to add more data and have the width of the bars adjust to accomodate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/findango/nfdST/

Comment: Thats a bingo! thank you very much for the explanation and the requested fixes. much appreciated/